# how to organize configure for plugins

Tags: c++, plugins, autotools

There is application called "runner" located in 'app/bin' directory. 
And there are a lot of plugin modules that should be located in 'app/bin/modules/' directory.

Mainly we are developing plugin modules and running them with "runner", There are no much work on "runner", only bugfixes.

Currently, to compile plugin, we compile whole project with "runner" and deploy to run environment.

Now I want reorganize it, so compile only source code of plugin.
The problem is: to compile modules we need to modify "configure.ac" to add module Makefile path, and then run "./configure"

(Second approach)
To avoid modification of main "configure.ac" I can create secondary "configure" files for plugin modules. In this case we will have a lot of "configure.ac"s. One module is implemented 1-2 days max.

I would like to hear experts' opinion for such situation.
Which approach is preferable ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the second approach. Adding to a system is better than modifying a system.